# SVG performance drop when animating 2 or more elements, RaphaelJS

Tags: performance, svg, raphael, performance-testing

I am testing SVG performance using RaphaelJS library.
My code works, can be found here: [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/eQYK2/)

When you type in textbox "1" and press "add", a rectangle will be generated on screen and 4 animations will loop on it- moving right, down, left, up (also rotating, scaling and changing colour).

Performance seems to be ok. But add another element on stage and the performance gets knocked down to minimum in 3-4 seconds. Checked in Chrome timeline, the thing that is getting stacked up is "Animation Frame Fired - > Install Timer".

Perhaps I am doing loop incorrectly? Altough next animation starts when the previous ends, through callback function. Or is it Raphael itself? Should I try doing this with SVG and SMIL? (Raphael uses VML)

Any ideas?

------------------------------------**UPDATE**--------------------------------------

With RaphaelJS I did bad animation loop hooks, see answer below.

But another problem that does occur - add 1 element 10 times and you can see how animations get distorted, not finishing their full cycle, or add 10 elements 1 time and after few seconds you can see delayed animations on some of the elements.

I made SMIL version [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/qa2XV/) (no Raphael here), animations do not lag, delay, but they get syncronized. Can anyone explain why? And how to make those animations NOT sync, but unique?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is you are recursively calling animations on a set.

So at the end of each animation, each element in the set calls an animation for the set again, so it spirals and grinds to a halt. You can get around this, by using 'this' instead of the set 'rectangles'.

```
//define 4 animations
var move_up = Raphael.animation({fill: "green", transform: "t0,0r360s1,1"}, 400, function(){ this.attr({"transform" : "t0,0"}); this.animate(move_right); });
var move_left = Raphael.animation({fill: "yellow", transform: "t0,100r270s0.5,0.5"}, 400, function(){ this.animate(move_up); });
var move_down = Raphael.animation({fill: "red", transform: "t100,100r180s1,1"}, 400, function(){ this.animate(move_left); });
var move_right = Raphael.animation({fill: "blue", transform: "t100,0r90s1.5,1.5"}, 400, function(){this.animate(move_down); });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eQYK2/1/)